# How do I troubleshoot an "Error #1090" trying to generate ASDoc?

Tags: apache-flex, asdoc

I've got a reasonably large Flex project and I'm trying to generate ASDoc documentation for it.  When I run asdoc, it gives me this error:

```
An unexpected error occurred.
Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.

(Location of error unknown)XSLT Error (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException): java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\projects\projectname\asdoc\toplevel_classes.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

I found a closed as could-not-reproduce [bug in Jira](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-19037) about single-quotes in a double-quoted public field initialiser, but I don't have any of those.  Any clues?

Comment: Tried, but couldn't replace. Can you post a minimal version of a class that gives rise to this error message?

Comment: @Amarghosh: Not at the moment, no -- my project has over four hundred classes and I've no idea which is causing the problem.  I was hoping for some hints to narrow the search space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Amarghosh prompted me to try running ASDoc individually on my classes, and it turns out that the error is due to a malformed ASDoc comment in my source:

```
    /**
     * @see Blah.blah
     *
     * Furbles the whatsit.
     */
```

needs to be:

```
    /**
     * Furbles the whatsit.
     *
     * @see Blah.blah
     */
```